# Operation with the same result every time

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do this operation

`y = (float) ((-1/1300)*(xsec))+40;`

where xsec is x to the second. 
With this function `double xsec = Math.pow((double)x, 2.0);` 
and after customized float in this way `xsec = (float) xsec;` and y is float. 
 So when i do the first operation the result is every time 40.0! I checked that xsec change, but even if xsec change the result is the same, 40.0! I suppose that 1/1300 is an operation with too many decimal digits. 
How can this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-1/1300 produces 0 under integer division. Use -1.0/1300.